# CONSULTAR PRECIO DESDE FORMULARIO

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

ESTOY APRENDIENDO DESARROLLO Y QUISIERA SABER COMO HACER ESTO.

MI FORMULARIO ES DE UNA TRANSPORTADORA QUE COBRA EL SERVICIO DEPENDIENDO DE QUE ELIJA EL CLIENTE.

```html
<form class="reserva" id="pricing" action="book.php" method="POST">
  <div class="topbooking">
    <h4 style="margin-top:-13px; display: -webkit-inline-box;">BOOK NOW!</h4>
    <span style="text-align:right" name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="bookcol1">
    <div class="col1p1">
    <label class="hoja" for="Text">Type</label>
    <select style="width: 320px" id="Type" name="Type">
      <option value="selected">Round Trip</option>
      <option value="">One Way</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="bookcol1">
  <div class="col1p1">
    <label class="hoja" for="Type or selec your Hotel">Type or select your Hotel</label>
    <select style="width:320px" name='Hotel' id="Hotel">
        <option value="none">Select your Hotel</option>
      <optgroup label="--San Jose Del Cabo - Zone 1--">
        <option value="zone1">Barcelo Grand Faro</option>
        <option value="zone1">Krystal Grand Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone1">Cabo Azul</option>
        <option value="zone1">Cabo Surf</option>
        <option value="zone1">Casa Natalia</option>
        <option value="zone1">Club La Costa</option>
        <option value="zone1">Coral Baja</option>
        <option value="zone1">El Encanto Inn</option>
        <option value="zone1">El Zalate Condos</option>
        <option value="zone1">The Grand Mayan at Vidanta</option>
        <option value="zone1">Holiday Inn Resort</option>
        <option value="zone1">Hyatt Place</option>
        <option value="zone1">Hyatt Ziva</option>
        <option value="zone1">La Jolla Condos</option>
        <option value="zone1">Las Olas</option>
        <option value="zone1">Vicery Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone1">Mananitas</option>
        <option value="zone1">Marisol</option>
        <option value="zone1">Mikonos</option>
        <option value="zone1">Mira Vista</option>
        <option value="zone1">Posada Real</option>
        <option value="zone1">Royal Decameron</option>
        <option value="zone1">Royal Park</option>
        <option value="zone1">Royal Solaris</option>
        <option value="zone1">Sampaguita</option>
        <option value="zone1">Suites Las Palmas</option>
        <option value="zone1">The Club at Presidente Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone1">Tropicana Inn</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="--Puerto Los Cabos Zone 2--">
        <option value="zone2">El Ganzo</option>
        <option value="zone2">JW Marriot Resort & Spa</option>
        <option value="zone2">Puerto Los Cabos Residential</option>
        <option value="zone2">Secrets Puerto Los Cabos</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="--Corridor Zone 2--">
        <option value="zone2">Chileno Bay</option>
        <option value="zone2">Club Regina</option>
        <option value="zone2">Dreams</option>
        <option value="zone2">El Dorado Residential</option>
        <option value="zone2">Baja Point</option>
        <option value="zone2">Hampton Inn & Suites By Hilton</option>
        <option value="zone2">Hilton Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone2">Las Ventanas</option>
        <option value="zone2">Marbella Suites en la Playa</option>
        <option value="zone2">Paradisus Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone2">One & Only Palmilla</option>
        <option value="zone2">Puerta del Sol</option>
        <option value="zone2">Querencia Residential Area</option>
        <option value="zone2">Marquis Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone2">The Westin Resort & Spa</option>
        <option value="zone2">Montage Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone2">Zoetry Casa del Mar</option>
        <option value="zone2">Grand Velas</option>
        <option value="zone2">Le Blanc Los Cabos</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Cabo San Lucas Zone 3">
        <option value="zone3">Bahia Hotel and Beach Club</option>
        <option value="zone3">Breathles Resort & Spa</option>
        <option value="zone3">Bungalows</option>
        <option value="zone3">Cabo del Sol Residential Area</option>
        <option value="zone3">Cabo San Lucas Inn</option>
        <option value="zone3">Cabo Villas</option>
        <option value="zone3">Cabo Bello Residential</option>
        <option value="zone3">The Resort at Pedregal</option>
        <option value="zone3">Cabo Pedregal Hotel</option>
        <option value="zone3">Casa Dorada At Medano Beach</option>
        <option value="zone3">Casa Pablito</option>
        <option value="zone3">Casa Rafael</option>
        <option value="zone3">Cascadas</option>
        <option value="zone3">Comfort Inn</option>
        <option value="zone3">El Ameyal</option>
        <option value="zone3">Esperanza</option>
        <option value="zone3">Fairfield Inn By Marriot</option>
        <option value="zone3">Fiesta Americana Grand</option>
        <option value="zone3">Sandos Finisterra</option>
        <option value="zone3">Soleado Beach & Spa Resort</option>
        <option value="zone3">Hacienda Beach</option>
        <option value="zone3">Hacienda del Mar Time Share </option>
        <option value="zone3">Hacienda Encantada</option>
        <option value="zone3">Holiday Inn Express</option>
        <option value="zone3">Hotel Castillo Blarney</option>
        <option value="zone3">Hotel Hacienda</option>
        <option value="zone3">Los Cabos Golf Resort</option>
        <option value="zone3">Los Milagros</option>
        <option value="zone3">Los Patios</option>
        <option value="zone3">Mar de Cortez</option>
        <option value="zone3">Marina Cabo Plaza</option>
        <option value="zone3">Marina View Villas</option>
        <option value="zone3">Solmar</option>
        <option value="zone3">Marina Fiesta</option>
        <option value="zone3">Marina Sol</option>
        <option value="zone3">Me Cabo</option>
        <option value="zone3">Misiones del Cabo</option>
        <option value="zone3">Pedregal Residential Area</option>
        <option value="zone3">Playa Grande</option>
        <option value="zone3">Plaza Nautica Condominiums Hotel</option>
        <option value="zone3">Portofino Hotel</option>
        <option value="zone3">Pueblo Bonito Los Cabos</option>
        <option value="zone3">Pueblo Bonito Rose</option>
        <option value="zone3">Quinta del Sol</option>
        <option value="zone3">Riu Palace</option>
        <option value="zone3">Riu Santa Fe</option>
        <option value="zone3">Seven Crown</option>
        <option value="zone3">Sheraton Hotel</option>
        <option value="zone3">Siesta Suites</option>
        <option value="zone3">Sirena del Mar</option>
        <option value="zone3">Grand Solmar</option>
        <option value="zone3">Terrasol</option>
        <option value="zone3">The Cape Thompson Pedregal</option>
        <option value="zone3">Villa Del Arco</option>
        <option value="zone3">Villa Del Palmar</option>
        <option value="zone3">Villa La Estancia</option>
        <option value="zone3">Villa Serena</option>
        <option value="zone3">Tesoro Los Cabos</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="--Cabo San Lucas Pacific Side--">
        <option value="pacificside">Montecristo Residential Area</option>
        <option value="pacificside">Pueblo Bonito Pacifica</option>
        <option value="pacificside">Pueblo Bonito Sunset Beach</option>
        <option value="pacificside">Diamante</option>
        <option value="pacificside">Quivira Residential</option>
        <option value="pacificside">Rancho San Lucas</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="--Others Locations--">
        <option value="todossantos">Todos Santos</option>
        <option value="losbarriles">Los Barriles</option>
        <option value="lapaz">La Paz</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bookcol1">
    <div class="col1p1">
    <label class="hoja" for="Passengers">Passengers</label>
    <select class="passengers" name='Passengers' id="passengers">
      <option value="sg">1</option>
      <option value="sg">2</option>
      <option value="sg">3</option>
      <option value="sg">4</option>
      <option value="sg">5</option>
      <option value="sg">6</option>
      <option value="bg">7</option>
      <option value="bg">8</option>
      <option value="bg">9</option>
      <option value="bg">10</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

ESTOS SERAN LOS SIGUIENTES PRECIOS

IDHOTEL| TYPE   | PASSENGERSS  | PRECIO

ZONE1 , ONE WAY ,    1 A 6               $60

ZONE1 , ROUND TRIP , 1 A 6       $105

ZONE1 , ONE WAY ,    7 A 10       $75

ZONE1 , ROUND TRIP , 7 A 10      $125

ZONE2 , ONE WAY ,    1 A 6       $70

ZONE2 , ROUND TRIP , 1 A 6       $125

ZONE2 , ONE WAY ,    7 A 10      $80

ZONE2 , ROUND TRIP , 7 A 10      $140

Comment: **QUIERO QUE SE IMPRIMA EN LA PANTALLA EL RESULTADO**

Comment: No se entiende bien que quieres hacer, debes reformular tu pregunta sin usar mayúsculas en todo el texto y explicando mas tu problema y cual es el resultado esperado, no te haremos la tarea, solo te ayudamos con errores

Comment: Probablemente necesitas unos precios para zone1, zone2 . . . pacificside  etc. También necesitas un cociente para Round Trip; por ejemplo 2. En tu caso el valor de la `option` "Round Trip" es selected: También necesitas un valor para la `option` One Way, por ejemplo 1. El valor de la `option` para passengers no puede ser "sg" o "bg". tiene que ser un número. Por ejemplo: `<option value="5">5</option>`

Comment: (OP).toLowerCase()